# IntelliJ Python plugin & Run classpath

Tags: python, intellij-idea, classpath, pycharm

I have a project located at /home/myself/workspace/Project1, for which I created an SDK from a Python 2.7.3 Virtualenv I have setup.
This project uses some external code that I have in an accessible directory, e.g. /home/myself/LIBRARY; this directory contains several directories with code, docs etc....
For example, there is a module "important_util" located at /home/myself/LIBRARY/mymodule/important_util.py.

Now, I added the whole dir /home/myself/LIBRARY in the SDK Classpath, and in the Editor window it appears just fine. The imports and calls are recognized and I can also navigate through the code in LIBRARY directories.

The problem is that, when I try to run my program, it fails at the first import using LIBRARY!!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/myself/workspace/Project1/my_program.py", line 10, in <module>
      from mymodule import important_util as ut 
      ImportError: No module named mymodule
```

I also tried to add the same directories to the section "Global Libraries" in the Sources section...but no luck.

I can't seem to find a way to add this code to the Run classpath, how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Just as clarification, I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 12, Python plugin 2.10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have `__init__.py` in `mymodule` directory:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later. [©](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

**UPDATE**: In IntelliJ IDEA additional directories should be added as **Module Dependencies** or configured as `Libraries` (to be added to the **Dependencies**) instead of the `Classpath` tab of the Python SDK:

[image: Dependencies]

I've verified that this folder (`D:\dev\lib`) is added to the `PYTHONPATH` and import works.

Comment: I can confirm that I checked the __init__.py ad there is such a file in both /home/myself/LIBRARY/mymodule/ and also in the parent directory.

Note that, I repeat, the editor windows finds the module just fine: I can also click and navigate to the files of the module.
The only thing it doesn't work is the "Run"....

Any other idea?

Comment: Also, I can run the code just fine from Terminal. Only IntelliJ doesn't find 'mymodule'

Comment: I've updated the answer, in IDEA the elements to be added in `PYTHONPATH` are configured as [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html). This is different from PyCharm where they should be added to the `Paths` tab of the SDK.

Answer (score 14):

In IntelliJ 14 it's a little different, you are modules/eggs like so:

- Go to File -> Project Structure
- Now select Modules and then "Dependencies" tab
- Click the "+" icon and select "Library"
- Click "New Library" and select Java (I know it's weird...)
- Now choose multiple modules / egg and "OK".
- Select "Classes" from categories.
- Give your new library a name, "My Python not Java Library"
- And finally click "Add Selected"

Comment: Super-helpful - worked with Ultimate 2016.1. Why doesn't JetBrains allow adding a Python library, instead of calling it Java?

Answer (score 1):

From Version of 2017.1 adding it has been changed again. **There is no project structure in the file menu**. Writing current procedure down:

1. Go To Preference/Settings. **File -> Settings** (IDE Name -> Preferences for macOS)
2. Select **Build, Execution, Deployment**

[image]

3. Select **Python Interpreter**
4. Select on drop-down menu of **project interpreter** and select the path of path of version of Python required for the project.

[image]

5. Click on Apply and wait for few minutes to let IntelliJ index the python packages.

All error should be gone now and You should be able to see Python used in the project in the list of external libraries.

[image]

***Happy Coding.***

Comment: This explains how to change the SDK/interpreter, but the question was how to add an external directory, one not part of the the interpreter directories, to PYTHONPATH. Also, this answer addresses PyCharm, but the question was about the Python plugin for IDEA - the menu & window locations mentioned aren't the same.

Comment: The procedure given above will work for any IntelliJ IDE with Python plugin for IDEA Installed. In fact, Screenshots added in the answer are taken in Goglang IDE.

Comment: Ah - I do see why one would think that's a logical conclusion, but apparently it's incorrect. I'm using straight-up IDEA CE (2017.2.4) with the current Python plugin (2017.2.172.3968.33), and there is no "Python Interpreter" entry in the "Build, Execution, Deployment" prefs.