# in IntelliJ, showing "No module named xxx", but "xxx" is actually installed in my system

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide, python-import, python-module

My IntelliJ version is **15.0.3**, and have python plugin installed.

And when I open a python file in IntelliJ it's like below
[image]

Situation here is like below:

1. when I import these flagged modules in terminal, everything works fine.
2. running this python file in IntelliJ, is also fine

It's **only the red underlying warning** annoying me.

I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102908/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-common-python-modules), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994846/intellij-python-plugin-run-classpath) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm), but none works for me.

Could anyone please tell me how to get rid of it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the site-packages path of your interpreter.

For that you have to:

1. go to Project Structure
2. choose Global Libraries
3. choose your Python interpreter
4. press + at the upper left corner
5. choose the site-package path of your interpreter
6. choose "Classes"

also add your python interpreter root directory in the same way.

Comment: I'm trying to use mysql.connector and experiencing the same problem as the asker, but following this did not solve it for me (site-packages was already in library list). Any other ideas?

Comment: also didn't work for me, however use `python3 -m site` to find your site-package path

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems: cannot import manually installed module. I try to add classpath in Mac environment parameters and intellij SDKs, but it doesn't work. My final solution is to add the classpath of the module to Run/Debug Configurations:

Open Run/Debug Configurations and select your unittest class:

> Run --> Edit Configurations...

Add your module's classpath to Environment variables: 
[image]