# How can I get IntelliJ to index libraries in my Python Conda environment?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, conda

I am using Python with Conda to manage my environment and libraries. Does anyone know how to get IntelliJ (with the Python plugin) or PyCharm to add the libraries in my Conda environment to my project?

It only pulls in site packages even when I select ~/anaconda/bin/python as my Python Interpreter.

Comment: I have found the 'IntelliJ 14 it's a little different' answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994846/intellij-python-plugin-run-classpath) but that requires adding each lib on its own .. was hoping for something easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ned to change your `Project Interpreter` to point to `$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python` where `$CONDA_PREFIX` is the *location* of your conda env.  The `$CONDA_PREFIX` environment location you're looking for should be in the second column of the output from `conda info --envs`.