# Add local python module to the classpath in IntelliJ

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm, classpath

I am trying to run/debug my python project from IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1. I have defined a python SDK, a Django local server (as the project uses Django as a template language), the PYTHONPATH is properly defined, etc. If I execute

```
python manage.py runserver
```

from my MacOS terminal, the server starts normally.
When I am trying to run my IntelliJ configuration, it fails, with message:

```
 /usr/bin/python2.7 -d /Users/my_user/dev/github/my_project/manage.py runserver 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_user/dev/github/my_project/manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    paths = importlib.import_module('settings.' + server + '.paths')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/my_user/dev/github/my_project/settings/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    paths = importlib.import_module('my_project.settings.' + server + '.paths')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named my_project.settings.local.paths
```

The `settings.local` folder does contains the `__init__.py` file, and also `settings` folder and the root folder of my project.
Doing a few hours of research over the internet I have realised that the main problem is to include local modules on the classpath, so they are available for server startup. For PyCharm, this is clearly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992894/182840), and I was able to run the server from PyCharm. However, when trying to do the same thing in IntelliJ, this never works. Some people write about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994846/intellij-python-plugin-run-classpath) for example, but that didn't worked out for me.

I have tried using a system interpreter and also a virtual environment, created with PyCharm, with no luck. I am using python 2.7, Django 1.11 and MacOS High Sierra. Is this even possible with IntelliJ? I wonder why would people buy PyCharm if the same things can be accomplished (and so much more) with IntelliJ. Also, I have noticed that when I change a setting in IntelliJ run profile (the Django local server profile), this change is reflected back in PyCharm and viceversa. This seems to me like a bug from JetBrains, as two distinct apps somehow share the same config, probably due to the fact that the same project is loaded in both apps.

Comment: Hi. Where exacty do you store ``my_project``? Could you please provide your project layout/structure and Django facet settings?

Comment: The my_project folder is the root of the project. The settings.local.paths missing module is a folder from the project. Django facet is as follows:
- Django project root: Users/my_user/dev/github/my_project
- Settings: settings/local/settings.py
- Do not use Django test runner: unchecked
- Manage script: manage.py (located in the root of my_project)
- Environment variables: none specified there
- Folder path to track files: migrations
Enable framework detection: checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in fact trivial, as clarified with JetBrains support: I needed to set the parent folder of `my_project` as content root (`/Users/my_user/dev/github/`), instead of using `/Users/my_user/dev/github/my_project/` directly. This was needed because the source code contained imports from module `my_project` which could not be resolved, as there was no subfolder `my_project` inside of my main project folder. I implemented this change in `Project settings -> Modules` view, `Project settings -> Facets` view and also in the run configuration.